# How to optimize value to range comparison using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

*(First time posting here, so apologies in advance)*

I would like to get the names and number of events for top 10 countries over a specific time period (last 1, 3, 7, 30 and 90 days). My current solution works, but is too slow for the number of events I receive (about 500 per hour).

Using Python 3.11.4 and Django 4.1.7 with a MySQL database.

### Test

Here is a test with the events from the last day (8,802). The timing may not be overly precise, as it was done with the simple `datetime.now() - start` method.

- Retrieve events:  0:00:00.197001
- Get top 10 locations:  0:01:12.714176
- Total:  0:01:12.911177

### Models

I have a table of Events with the following model:

```py
class Events(models.Model):
    idhoneypot = models.IntegerField(db_column="idHoneypot")
    tshoneypot = models.CharField(db_column="tsHoneypot", max_length=24)
    tsserver = models.DateTimeField(db_column="tsServer")
    srcip = models.CharField(db_column="srcIP", max_length=16)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    f1 = models.TextField()
    f2 = models.TextField()
    f3 = models.TextField()
```

Furthermore, I have an `IP2Location` table (DB1 from https://lite.ip2location.com/ modified to use ISO-3 codes) of IP ranges and the corresponding location with the following model:

```py
class IP2Location(models.Model):
    from_IP = models.IntegerField(db_column="FromIP", primary_key=True)
    to_IP = models.IntegerField(db_column="toIP")
    country_code = models.CharField(db_column="CountryCode", max_length=3)
    country = models.CharField(db_column="Country", max_length=250)
```

*The table also containse a unique B-Tree index using `from_IP` and `to_IP`*

### Current solution

My current solution is the following:

```py
def get_top10(timespan: int = 1) -> dict[str,int]:
    start = t = datetime.now()
    limit = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=timespan)
    ips = [ip_to_dec(e["srcip"]) for e in Events.objects.filter(tsserver__gte=limit).values("srcip")]
    print(len(ips), " Events")
    print("Retrieve events: ", datetime.now()-t)
    t = datetime.now()

    locations = {}
    for ip in ip_list:
        if ip in locations:
            locations[ip]["count"] += 1
        else:
            locations[ip] = {
                "country": IP2Location.objects.get(from_IP__lte=ip, to_IP__gte=ip).country,
                "count": 1,
            }

    countries = defaultdict(int)
    for loc in locations.values():
        countries[loc["country"]] += loc["count"]

    print("Get top 10 locations: ", datetime.now()-t)
    print("Total: ", datetime.now()-start)

    return dict(
        sorted(
            countries.items(),
            key=lambda item: item[1],
            reverse=True,
        )[:10]
    )
```

Here is the `ip_to_dec` function used above, which converts the dot-separated IP string into the decimal format:

```py
def ip_to_dec(ip: str) -> int:
    return sum(int(octet) << (24 - 8 * i) for i, octet in enumerate(ip.split(".")))
```

### Tried improvement

I have tried the following to try and combine reduce the number of queries, but instead of giving me the number of events for each country, it gives me the number of IPs which caused events from each country:

```py
condition_set = set(Q(from_IP__lte=ip, to_IP__gte=ip) for ip in ip_list)
conditions = Q()
for condition in condition_set:
    conditions |= condition

countries = (
    IP2Location.objects.filter(conditions)
    .values("country")
    .annotate(count=Count("country"))
    .order_by("-count")[:10]
)
```